# Как загрузить картинку на сайт и сразу ее использовать?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, файлы, изображения

Есть например инпут type="file" и есть сразу несколько вопросов которые не смог найти нормально в интернете, возможно не умею гуглить. Я НЕ ищу готовых решений, буду благодарен за ссылку на правильную статью или простого примера.

1. Надо ограничить расширение файла - только изображения, и максимальную высоту и ширину.
2. Надо использовать изображение на сайте сразу же когда загрузили - например, поставить его фоном, отправить в php обработчик для сохранения. Возможно вставить как-то в какую-то переменную, просто раньше не приходилось заниматься чем-то похожим.

Поправка - нашел как уточнить расширение файла, остальное - не знаю

Comment: 2) ajax на сохранение файла, в ответ принимает путь к файлу и сразу меняет background img нужного элемента

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Надо ограничить расширение файла - только изображения, и максимальную высоту и ширину.
> 2. Надо использовать изображение на сайте сразу же когда загрузили - например, поставить его фоном

Вот так это делается.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Вешаем события на file, как только файл выбран
  $('.bg-img').change(function() {
    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    var fileExt = ['jpeg', 'png']; // Разрешённые расширения файлы
    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Сравнивает выбранный с разрашенными по расширению файла
    if ($.inArray($(this).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), fileExt) !== -1) {
      // Объект фотки для проверки размеров
      var img = new Image();
      // Создание УРЛ для фотки
      var file_url = URL.createObjectURL($(this).prop('files')[0]);
      //----------------------------------------------------------------
      // Подгрузка фотки на страницу
      img.onload = function() {
        var allowed_w = 500;
        var allowed_h = 500;
        // Разрешунные размеры
        if (img.width < allowed_w && img.height < allowed_h) {
          //----------------------------------------------------------------
          // Объект которому поменяют бэкграунд
          $('.container').css('background', 'url(' + file_url + ') no-repeat');
          //----------------------------------------------------------------
        } else { // Выбран неразрешенный файл
          $('.bg-img').val('') // Очистит название фотки
          // поменяйте на alert, чтобы юзер увидел
          console.error('Allowed Width: ' + allowed_w + '; Height: ' + allowed_h);
        }
      }
      img.src = file_url // Нужно для проверки размеров фотки
      //----------------------------------------------------------------
      // $(this).prop('files')[0] // в данном контексте сам выбраный файл
    } else { // Выбран неразрешенный файл
      $(this).val('')
      // поменяйте на alert, чтобы юзер увидел
      console.error('Only allowed types: ' + fileExt.join(', '));
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form action="">
    <input type="file" class="bg-img">
  </form>
</div>
```

- [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) - создает *DOMString* содержащий *URL* с указанием на объект. Объект может быть *File* или *Blob*.

Comment: Спасибо, познавательно) А как например через ajax отправить изображение в php обработчик?

Comment: @shumik_UA не за что. Это уже другой вопрос, задайте отдельно. К новому вопросу, добавьте код с вашими попытками, опишите, что работает, а что нет. Какого результата, хотели бы добиться. Если, этот ответ вам, подходит, то отметьте как принятый.